# How to force flex to shrink responsive images to fit to it's container in column direction?

Tags: css, flexbox

I have tried lots of tricks to force the responsive images to fit to the flex container when the direction is set to `flex-direction: column;` but none of them works. I have to mention that it works well with other elements such as text or when flex direction is set to `flex-direction: row;` but not in my case. I have tried `flex:1;`,`flex-shrink`,`flex-grow`,`max-height` properties to achieve what I want but all failed.

How to create a flex container with one column and three rows when the size of the container is fixed (`width:234px; height:279px`) and the height of each row is flexible in order **to show 3 images at their maximum size**? If they couldn't fit into their container then shrink them but keep the aspect ratio.

[My codepen.io code here](https://codepen.io/microtorrent135/pen/qmOOpL)

Comment: That's 6 problems in one question. I would suggest you consider focusing on one problem at a time per question. Also, please include all relevant code in the question itself, per SO guidelines.

Comment: Keep in mind that there is no use in applying `flex-grow` and `justify-content` to the same item. If you use `flex-grow`, that consumes all available space, leaving `justify-content` with no space left to function. If you remove `flex-grow`, the `justify-content: center` will work in your demo.

Comment: Also, flex items, by default, cannot be smaller than the size of their content. So your images may overflow, regardless of `flex-shrink` and `flex-basis`, unless you override the default. Refer to the duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

add

```
img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

to your code and you will get the results you want :)

Comment: @s-zaib I mentioned that I have used that but it doesn't work. I want to control the height and width of the image not only width.

Comment: do you have a live demo of it?

Comment: max-height: 100%;
and 
max-width: 100%;

makes image responsive respective to container of image :)

Comment: do you find it helpful?